# How to loop through an existing dataframe and create multiple new dataframes based on selected existing columns of all combinations

Tags: list, loops, combinations

I have a data frame which looks like this:

```
    [1y        2y        3y        4y        5y        6y
1y  0.089665  0.053792  0.012451 -0.002395  0.019095  0.010208
2y  0.053792  0.053755  0.008856  0.003674  0.029976  0.008558
3y  0.012451  0.008856  0.117032  0.043895 -0.036560 -0.020077
4y -0.002395  0.003674  0.043895  0.091666 -0.016293  0.033488
5y  0.019095  0.029976 -0.036560 -0.016293  0.064131  0.025783
6y  0.010208  0.008558 -0.020077  0.033488  0.025783  0.096131][1]
```

However, I would like to loop through this dataframe and create multiple new dataframes (with each dataframe having 3 columns) based on the existing column names.

I have used:
from itertools import combinations
cc = list(combinations(cov_matrix.columns,3)), to come up with a list of the different unique combinations of the column headers of the new dataframes I need i.e.

[('1y', '2y', '3y'), ('1y', '2y', '4y'), ('1y', '2y', '5y'), ('1y', '2y', '6y'), ('1y', '3y', '4y'), ('1y', '3y', '5y'), ('1y', '3y', '6y'), ('1y', '4y', '5y'), ('1y', '4y', '6y'), ('1y', '5y', '6y'), ('2y', '3y', '4y'), ('2y', '3y', '5y'), ('2y', '3y', '6y'), ('2y', '4y', '5y'), ('2y', '4y', '6y'), ('2y', '5y', '6y'), ('3y', '4y', '5y'), ('3y', '4y', '6y'), ('3y', '5y', '6y'), ('4y', '5y', '6y')]

In this case my desired output will be 20 different new data frames (3 by 3) based on the 20 different combinations of the column headers I have above.

One example of a dataframe output will be
[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vF27S.png)```
Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

```
#My current codes are as follow:

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_excel(r"C:\Users\s\Documents\Dummy Excel.xlsx", sheet_name="Usd")

print(df)

cov_matrix = df.cov()
print(cov_matrix)

from itertools import combinations
cc = list(combinations(cov_matrix.columns,3))
print(cc)

for i in cc:
    new_df = cov_matrix[[i]].copy()
```

However I get the error,

> KeyError: "None of [Index([('1y', '2y', '3y')], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"

Comment: Hi Marcus, do you mind checking your formatting?